# What is direct speech form of these sentences? 1. He asked me if I had come by train or by bus 2. She wanted to know who we had invited to the party

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure, past-perfect, reported-speech

> 1. He asked me if I had come by train or by bus
> 2. She wanted to know who we had invited to the party

I Know the basics about direct and indirect speech. But I doubt if my answers are correct. I'm new to this topic.

1. He said, "Did you come by train or by bus"
2. ??

Comment: "Is this correct?" questions are off-topic. Yes, (1) is correct except that it needs a question mark. You haven't even attempted the second one, but it should be straightforward enough.

Comment: @KateBunting I don't know what the answer to the second one would be.

Comment: #1 ***He asked** "Did you come by train or by bus?"* #2 ***She asked** "Who did you invite to the party?"*  In both cases, ***<pronoun> asked*** can be moved to ***after*** the (quoted) "direct speech". That's just a stylistic choice. Note that  <pronoun> can be replaced by <proper_noun> (John, Jane), *in which case* it's often more idiomatic to "invert" subject+verb: #1a  *"Did you come by train or by bus?" **asked John,*** but that inversion is not idiomatic *before* the quoted speech, where only ***John asked** "Did you come by train or by bus?"* is normally used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your direct speech form for the first sentence is correct:

- He said, "Did you come by train or by bus?"

For the second sentence, here's the direct speech form:

- She said, "Who did you invite to the party?"

Comment: I wonder if the second question has an alternative answer or not?

Comment: She asked us, "Who have you invited to the party?"

Comment: @KavehBehnia "She asked, 'Whom did you invite to the party?'"

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as the "direct speech form".

You can talk about the "form" of a verb or a phrase:  "did" is past tense form of "do", or "to be driven" is the passive form of "to drive".

There is no direct speech form.  It is not possible to reconstruct the exact words used from the report about the words used.  Just like you can't reconstruct the exact events of a news story from the news report.

You don't know if he said, "Did you take the train, or ride the bus?" or, "Tell me about your journey, were you on the train or bus?" or even "I usually take the train instead of the bus, how about you?"  All three are different ways in which he could have asked if you had come by train or by bus.

In five minutes I could suggest 20 different ways in which someone could express that they want to know about the party invites.